# Bearer Token in Node.js command line client http.request - Unauthorized

Tags: javascript, node.js, oauth-2.0, authorization

I'm developing a Node.js command line client which calls a REST API.

I have no issues calling non-authenticated gets and posts, but after I authenticate and receive my Bearer token, I'm not able to get an authorized response.

With what little samples are out there, I've simplified my call for test purposes with the following:

```js
var options =
    {
        host: "localhost",
        port: "62405",
        path: "/api/Job",
        method: 'GET',
        headers:
        {
            Authorization: "Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJVbml0VGVzdGVyQG12cHNpLmNvbSIsInJvbGUiOiJ1c2VyIiwiSkFNU1RlbmVudElkIjoiNDIiLCJXaW5kb3dzSWRlbnRpdHkiOiJVbml0VGVzdGVyQG12cHNpLmNvbSIsImlzcyI6Ik1WUFNJIiwiYXVkIjoiSkFNU0FEQ2xpZW50SWQiLCJleHAiOjE0MzEzOTY4NzEsIm5iZiI6MTQzMTM1MzY3MX0.iYYX3TjcJONKhbNDqxG2hNGFwxGV0zG2m3rJ1wqmzIw"
        }
    };

    var callback = function (res) {
        console.log(res.statusCode);
        console.log(res.headers);

        var str = "";

        res.on("data", function(chunk) {
            str += chunk;
        });

        res.on("end", function() {
            console.log(str);
        });
    };

    var request = require('http').request(options, callback);
    request.end();
```

Instead of receiving the reply, I'm getting a 401 with a response message of "Authorization has been denied for this request."

Again, this is a simplified version of my extensible code... but any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

---

Clarification, when I use Postman and manually put in the token into the Authentication header, I receive an authorized (and the expected) response.

Comment: Is the API accepting requests via HTTP (meaning, is it not enforcing HTTPS)?

Comment: Good question, Luis. It is accepting HTTP requests (we don't have a cert for our development environment). I actually login (authenticate) and receive the token, then save it in a local JSON file. This is done via an http request.

Comment: Have you tried to do the same request using a request generator (like Postman) or Fiddler? I've found it is usually easier and faster to do some trial/error tests with such a tool (if the API is not documented enough) to identify which are the parameters that the API is expecting and work.

Comment: I was able to get the proper response in Postman simply by adding the following Header:
Authorization: Bearer <token>

Comment: OK, I would then look at the traffic that your nodejs app is actually sending. I usually using fiddler to do that, then you can easily spot and compare what your app is sending vs. what you know works successfully.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, Luis. I do see a difference between Postman's content length and the one I'm sending. Unfortunately, Fiddler can't see calls from a Node.js client or a Studio.NET typescript test, but I am trying to use Wireshark.